# File contents stops updating on windows share

Tags: c#, windows, share

I have a program that (repeatedly) reads contents of a file and, if new data arrives, do some processing. Reading is quite straightforward, something like

```
class Reader
{
    FileStream fs_ = null;
    StreamReader sr_ = null;

    Reader(string filename)
    {
        fs_= new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete);
        sr_ = new StreamReader(fs_);
    }

    void Read()
    {
        string line;
        while (line = sr_.ReadLine())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Method Read() is polled every 300 ms. There is some piece of code that closes and reopens file in case of its renaming/deletion by external actors.

Generally, it works ok, but sometimes (I've encountered this two times during last month) strange thing appears. File on a share reporting correct length, but when trying to read from it, shows one and a half of string and rest of file with zeroed (0x00, not '0') contents. Moreover, I got same picture when trying to read the file via any external text/binary editor from the same machine that hosted my program. From other machines on the network file is read without any problems and shows full contents. The problem persists until I reboot the machine with my program.

Any idea what happens and how can I fix it?